# How do I show some simple HTML (text/images) in the sidebar of my Drupal 7 theme?

Tags: drupal

I've created a theme using Zen and all is well. I want to display some simple text and images in the sidebar, but I don't understand Drupal well enough to know what I'm doing.

I have worked with Joomla which allows one to create a new HTML module, populate it, and then select where it appears on the page (and also of course which pages). I don't see this with Drupal. I've seen some talk about using the theme's templates, but I need for my client to be able to change the text (and/or images) without knowing anything about that.

It would be best to create an article and be able to make that article appear in the side bar somehow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with [blocks](http://drupal.org/documentation/blocks). Blocks allow you to place content items on a page. Where abouts the block appears is up to you and how the theme is configured. To create a block click "Admminister -> Site building -> blocks".

If you have other Drupal questions, try [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/).

Good luck